# What were some popular wizarding foods in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Wizarding World, there are many foods not found in the Muggle world.

- Cauldron Cakes
- Butterbeer

Does anyone else know of any other popular Wizarding foods?

Comment: Firewhiskey. Bertie Bott's Every-Flavour Beans.

Comment: Chocolate Frogs.

Comment: http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizworld/food.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Peppermint Toads
- Couldron Cakes
- Bertie Bott's Every-Flavour Beans
- Chocolate Frogs
- Cockroach Clusters
- ButterBeer
- Pumpkin Juice (one of the favourites at Hogwarts)
- Acid Pops
- Rock Cakes
- Maggoty Haggis  (Popular amongst the ghosts)
- Wizard crackers (source: [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/why-christmas-at-hogwarts-is-better-than-any-other))
- Droobles Best Blowing Gum
- Liquorice Wands

Sources: Pottermore, [Leaky Couldron](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2012/06/07/pottermore-food-trolley-2/), the books.

Comment: I don’t think there’s any indication that bouillabaisse is a wizarding food as such; it’s just a specialty the house-elves cooked up when the Frenchies arrived.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe I should remove it from the list. I assumed it as a regular food at Beauxbatons :)

Comment: It probably is—but it’s not specific to wizards. (Nor are pumpkin pasties or pumpkin juice, by the way, though pumpkin juice was probably exceedingly rare before the Potterverse popularised it.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for pointing out. We don't have them in Asia, so I assumed it a wizarding food (the name looked funny)  :D

Comment: They’re not exactly common (at least not in my experience), but [pasties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasty) do come in all sorts of varieties, including sweet flavours like pumpkin.

Comment: Rock cakes are also a real food.  You might mean Hagrid's Rock Cakes, which I hope don't exist